# How do i sum net amount based on policyno in xml tag by using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

output should like :

PolicyNo   NetAmount
POL-01     300
POL-02     500

below query gives me Total of both policy instead of group wise Please guide me for the same.

Below is my xml :

```
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail> 
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail> 
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail>  
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail>
```

and my xquery is :

```
#xquery(let $sas := StatementDetail
let $sum :=sum($sas/NetAmount[. castable as xs:double])
return <StatementDetail><NetAmount>{$sum}</NetAmount></StatementDetail>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it by using BaseX v.9.4.1

The solution needs to use `group by` clause to get a proper `sum` calculation.

XQuery

```
declare context item := document {
<root>
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail> 
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail> 
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail>  
<StatementDetail>  
        <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
        <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>              
</StatementDetail> 
</root>
};

<root>
{
  for $x in ./root/StatementDetail
  let $PolicyNo := fn:upper-case($x/PolicyNo)
  group by $PolicyNo
  order by $PolicyNo
  return <statement>
        <StatementDetail>{$PolicyNo}</StatementDetail>
        <NetAmountSum>{sum($x/NetAmount)}</NetAmountSum>
      </statement>
}
</root>
```

Output

```
<root>
  <statement>
    <StatementDetail>POL-01</StatementDetail>
    <NetAmountSum>300</NetAmountSum>
  </statement>
  <statement>
    <StatementDetail>POL-02</StatementDetail>
    <NetAmountSum>500</NetAmountSum>
  </statement>
</root>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply i will implement it and let u know soon.

Comment: I believe you're missing a `return` right before the start of the constructor, but otherwise it works!

Comment: @JackFleeting, thanks for the comment. I provided a minimal reproducible example. Including XQuery  engine and its version. So the answer was created and fully tested in BaseX.

Comment: Yes it does; I missed the declaration at the top...

Comment: @JackFleeting.  Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: It's going to be difficult since I need to stay anonymous here (for various reasons); we can try my email, if that works.

Comment: Great; will connect later today.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky above code is working for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: @RimeshPatil. Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"